Проблема с вводом данных

Здравствуйте, проблема с счётом и вводом данных.
Почему получается 14 и 6ти?

По-моему, должно выводиться 58, а не 14. Но проверять мне лень.

А код в вопрос надо текстом добавлять. Впрочем, в данном случае на текст фиг ответишь, потому что 14 там быть не должно...

Всё-таки не поленился и проверил.
Я очень удивлён, но ответ на твой вопрос - потому что у разработчиков сайта programiz руки кривые. Судя по всему у них какая-то фигня с вводом. Я могу получить как правильный вариант 58 без перевода строки, так и сомнительный 14 на новой строке. При том, что запускается один и тот же код после его изменения туда-обратно, которое вообще не должно влиять на результат.


Лучше используй tio.run

PS: Console.Read не предназначен для считывания чиcел.

58 из символа "6"=0x36, а 14 из LF=0xA?

@MBo, видимо да, но всё равно у них ввод глючит)
